# Issues finding a google sheet in my drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I am trying to get the data from a google sheet that is placed in my drive.The name of the file is "AnexoSepe".My code is simple:
"

```
var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("AnexoSepe");
 if (!sheet) {
    console.error('Not Found.');
    return;
 }
```

.
The error that comes out is: **"Error Not Found.** ". I have spent a long time trying to figure out why is giving me this error. Everything should be all right as the google sheet file called "AnexoSepe" is located in my drive with permissions granted. It has one row of data for now. Can someone help me out?. It is driving me nuts

Comment: You probably should be using DriveApp.getFilesByName().  A class Sheet is one of the tabs in a spreadsheet.  A spreadsheet is a file located in your drive. You should really read the documentation for every method and pay close attention to what kind of an object is returned.

Comment: - [google-apps-script reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)

Answer (score 1):

It's unfortunate that Google decided to use the name Sheets for Spreadsheets because the class name "Sheet" is the name given to what Excel refers to as a Worksheet.  So it's easy for newcomers to get them mixed up.  Spreadsheets are files and can be found using the various methods of DriveApp Class.  There are references below for various methods used in this code which search for files by name and displays the result in a Sheet.

You can use this as start for a script to find files by name.  It returns the name,type,parent folder and id.  Ids are unique for every file not names.

```
function myfunk0(name) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  if(name) {
    var fA = [];
    const files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(name);
    while(files.hasNext()) {
      let f = files.next();
      let pA = [];
      let ps = f.getParents();
      while(ps.hasNext()) {
        pA.push(ps.next())
      }
      fA.push([f.getName(),f.getMimeType(),pA.join(', '),f.getId()])
    }
    fA.unshift(["Name","MimeType","Parents","Id"])
    Logger.log(JSON.stringify(fA).replace(/],/g,'],\n'));
    sh.clearContents();
    sh.getRange(1,1,fA.length,fA[0].length).setValues(fA);
  }
}
```

This is what Sheet0 looks like for a file on my drive

| Name | MimeType | Parents | Id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ScriptFunctions | text/plain | ScriptIds | Redacted |

With the id redacted.  You should get use to finding files by id because that is what is unique.

- [Default Parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters)
- [google-apps-script reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)
- [javascript reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)
- [Range.setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)
- [DriveApp.getFilesByName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfilesbynamename)
- [Spreadsheet.getSheetByName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename)

Answer (score 0):

You're using a completely wrong AppsScript class. `SpreadsheetApp` class is used to read and manipulate a spreadsheet, not Drive files.
What your script does is it takes an active (let's say currently opened) spreadsheet and gets a sheet (spreadsheet's "tab") called AnexoSepe.

What you need to do is use [getFilesByName](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app?hl=pl#getFilesByName(String)) method of DriveApp class, like that:

```js
var sheets = DriveApp.getFilesByName("AnexoSepe");
return sheets
```

But take into consideration that this method returns a [FileIterator](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file-iterator).

Comment: What I want is to read a google spread  sheet from my drive and then transfer the data to a google doc template that I also have in my drive. So that is why I am trying to access the last row of my google sheet. More code for you to see: "function onFormSubmit() {
  const googleDocTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById(docTemplateId);
  const destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(destinationFolderId);

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("AnexoSepe");

if (!sheet) {
  console.error('Not Found.');
  return;
}
  const lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();........."

Comment: It does not return an array. It returns a [FileIterator](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file-iterator), and your proposal to get the length by using `sheets.length` would not provide any information as it's undefined.